# How to install Windows Media Player 10 in a 64-bit architecture?

Tags: windows, wine, 64-bit, media, winetricks

I am trying to install WMP10 through winetricks. I enter the command `winetricks wmp10` and get this output:

```
~$ winetricks wmp10

You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.

Executing w_do_call wmp10
Executing load_wmp10

Installer doesn't support 64-bit architecture. Use a 32-bit WINEPREFIX instead.
```

Every time I open winetricks, it gives me this warning. I tried adding i386 architecture like is suggested in another thread, but it made no difference. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: There are lots of Linux native alternatives https://alternativeto.net/software/windows-media-player/?platform=linux

Answer (score 0):

Install WMP10 in a separate 32-bit prefix:

```
cd ~/
wget -q https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/raw/master/src/winetricks -O /home/$USER/winetricks
WINEPREFIX="/home/$USER/.wine32" WINEARCH=win32 wineboot
WINEPREFIX="/home/$USER/.wine32" sh ~/winetricks -q wmp10
```

Comment: That still outputs that `You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX` for me, and then `This package does not work on a 64-bit installation. You must use a prefix made with WINEARCH=win32`.

Comment: Edited, should work now. (I made a dumb mistake in the last command.)